# how to convert struct tm to time_t in c++

Tags: c++, mktime, time-t

the given function is a part of a class which is used to handle date and time.the file i parse needs to convert the given string data to time_t yet mktime does not work. why?

```
 struct tm DateTimeUtils::makeTime(string arrTime)//accepts in format"2315"means 11.15 pm
{
    struct tm neww;
    string hour = arrTime.substr(0,2);
    int hour_int = stoi(hour);
    neww.tm_hour=hour_int;//when this is directly printed generates correct value


    string minute = arrTime.substr(2,2);
    int minute_int = stoi(minute);
    neww.tm_min=(minute_int);//when this is directly printed generates correct value

    time_t t1 = mktime(&neww);//only returns -1
    cout<<t1;

    return neww;

}
```

Comment: There are not only tm_min and tm_hour in a tm structure. See here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: i modified the code by adding this :

struct tm DateTimeUtils::makeTime(string arrTime)
{
    struct tm neww;
    neww.tm_sec=0-61;
    neww.tm_mday=1-31;
    neww.tm_mon=0-11;
    neww.tm_year=1900;
    neww.tm_wday=0-6;
    neww.tm_yday=0-365;

    string hour = arrTime.substr(0,2);
    int hour_int = stoi(hour);
    neww.tm_hour=hour_int;


    string minute = arrTime.substr(2,2);
    int minute_int = stoi(minute);
    neww.tm_min=(minute_int);

    time_t t1 = mktime(&neww);
    cout<<t1;

    return neww;

}

still shows -1 @leyanpan

Comment: *"i modified the code..."* - great. now [modify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47938426/edit) to include an *addendum* with your changes. Walls of code won't belong in comments; they belong in the posted question, and ideally, they're minimized to exhibit only the problem to which your question pertains.

Answer (score 1):

From the [mktime(3) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime):

> `time_t` ... represents the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

Then you have the fields of `struct tm` and particularly this one:

> tm_year
>
> The number of years since 1900.

So basicaly if the `tm_year` is set to `0` and we do the math correctly, we get a `70` year difference that needs to be expressed in seconds, and that's probably too big.

You can solve this by initialising your `struct tm` value to the Epoch and use that as a base reference:

```
 struct tm DateTimeUtils::makeTime(string arrTime)//accepts in format"2315"means 11.15 pm
{
    time_t tmp = { 0 };
    struct tm neww = *localtime(&tmp);
    string hour = arrTime.substr(0,2);
    int hour_int = stoi(hour);
    neww.tm_hour=hour_int;//when this is directly printed generates correct value


    string minute = arrTime.substr(2,2);
    int minute_int = stoi(minute);
    neww.tm_min=(minute_int);//when this is directly printed generates correct value

    time_t t1 = mktime(&neww);//only returns -1
    cout<<t1;

    return neww;
}
```

Comment: `time_t` in most implementations is `long int`, which is an signed integer type. Therefore it is capable of having the same range in positive and negative values which is(on a 32 bit machine) roughly from -291 bilion years to +291 bilion years.

Comment: Note that `mktime()` is time-zone sensitive: Supplying `1970-01-01T00:00` won't yield `mktime(...) == 0` in most places of the world. So you would need to add the seconds/minutes/hours to the values you get out of the `localtime()` call, instead of just overwriting those values.

Comment: @Detonar 32 bit can represent 2^32 = 4294967296, there is approximately 31536000 seconds in a year. 4294967296 / 31536000 = 136. So actually you can represent 136 years, not billions of years. But for some reason on my machine mktime fails if i go above 68 years, which seems to be half of that theorical limit, not sure why though.

Comment: @Drax a `long int` on an 32 bit system represents 64 bit meaning from -2^63 to +2^63-1 which is -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807 seconds... And even if it were just a simple `int` it would be more than that 70 years difference you mentioned.

Comment: Well, if it were just a simple `int` that would explain it because `int` IS signed. But that would be weird.

Comment: @Detonar You are right, i can't seem to explain the practical behaviour i see on my machine with theoretical size limits. It might just be a hard coded limit of mktime on some platforms. I do still notice that if you go under that  amount everything works fine so the answer is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the struct before usage usually helps in this case:

```
struct tm neww;
memset((void *)&neww, 0, sizeof(tm));
```

Comment: still returning -1!

Comment: Then check what exact values are you passing. Maybe you passed wrong values like hour=30, minute=100 etc. Also what is `neww.tm_mday=1-31`? Are you passing -30?

Comment: neww.tm_sec=60;
    neww.tm_mday=1;
    neww.tm_mon=11;
    neww.tm_year=1900;
    neww.tm_wday=6;
    neww.tm_yday=365;

Comment: At least you can have conflicting day settings: tm_mday, tm_wday and tm_yday, specify just one of them. Also year=1900 is 1900+1900, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: struct tm DateTimeUtils::makeTime(string arrTime)
{
    struct tm neww;
    memset((void *)&neww, 0, sizeof(tm));
    neww.tm_sec=1;
    neww.tm_mday=1;
    neww.tm_mon=1;
    neww.tm_year=0;

    string hour = arrTime.substr(0,2);
    int hour_int = stoi(hour);
    neww.tm_hour=hour_int;


    string minute = arrTime.substr(2,2);
    int minute_int = stoi(minute);
    neww.tm_min=(minute_int);

    time_t t1 = mktime(&neww);
    cout<<t1;

    return neww;

}


this is the final code,but still mktime gives me -1

Comment: @tanvi rustagi - `neww.tm_sec=60` looks critical. try to avoid this.

Comment: @Detonar  yes i changed the values to :neww.tm_sec=1;
    neww.tm_mday=1;
    neww.tm_mon=1;
    neww.tm_year=0;

Comment: and what is `tm_hour`?

Comment: i'm reading that from a file which are values between 1 to 24...
cout<<neww.tm_hour generates the correct output

Comment: @tanvirustagi I cannot reproduce your problem. The code `#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 struct tm date = {
  .tm_sec = 60,
  .tm_mday = 1,
  .tm_mon = 11,
  .tm_year = 1900,
  .tm_wday = 6,
  .tm_yday = 365
 };
 time_t result = mktime(&date);
 printf("result = %lld\n", (long long)result);
}` does not print `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `time_t` is defined as 64 bit integer which resolves in a range of

**-2^63 to +2^63-1 (-9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807)**

which is roughly from -292 bilion years to +292 from the epoch.

However. If, fpor some reason, on your system `time_t` is just defined as 32 bit integer (16 bit embedded system or weird architecture or header files) we get a range from

**2^31 to 2^31-1 (-2147483648 to +2147483647)**

being roughly  from -68 years to +68 years.

You could solve this problem by redefining time_t before calling `mktime()`.

```
#define time_t long int
```

or if really using an 16 bit system

```
#define time_t long long int
```